# Extract path name component in jq

Tags: bash, jq

I have the following bash command

```
something something ... |
xargs -L 1 az aks list --subscription |
jq -r '.[] | "az aks get-credentials --name \(.name) --resource-group \(.resourceGroup) --subscription=\(.id)"'
```

This works except the final argument `\(.id)` is a string I need to substring using the following commands output embedded in the final output string

```
awk -F "/" '{print $3}' <<< "/subscriptions/I-need-Selecting/resourcegroups/blahblah/blahblah"
```

I cannot seem to get this command to execute in the outputted command - I cannot escape the `"` or `'` in the `awk` effectively.

The output from the `aks list --subscriptions` command looks something like

```js
[{"name": "foo", "resourceGroup": "bar", "subscription": "/subscriptions/I-need-Selecting/resourcegroups/blahblah/blahblah"},
... ]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying the first `az account list` command outputs something like `/subscriptions/I-need-Selecting/resourcegroups/blahblah/blahblah` and you want to extract just the thirs directory component from that? In `jq` or in the pipe?

Comment: the final string that is output contains a string of that format, that i need to use the `awk` command on, but i can't escape the quotes effectively, i just get syntax errors. I hope that makes sense. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Essentially i need this to execute  echo '"az aks get-credentials --name name --resource-group resourceGroup --subscription=$(awk -F "/" ''{print $3}'' <<< "/subscriptions/I-need-Selecting/r")"'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking, given

```sh
bash$ echo '[{"name": "tarzan", "resourceGroup": "froup", "id": "/subscriptions/I-need-Selecting/resourcegroups/blahblah/blahblah" }]' |
> jq -r '.[] | "az aks get-credentials --name \(.name) --resource-group \(.resourceGroup) --subscription=\(.id)"'
az aks get-credentials --name tarzan --resource-group froup --subscription=/subscriptions/I-need-Selecting/resourcegroups/blahblah/blahblah
```

... how to reduce the "subscription" parameter to just a substring, try

```
jq '.[] |  "az aks get-credentials --name \(.name) --resource-group \(.resourceGroup) --subscription=\(.id | split("/")[3])"'
```

It's not impossible to run Awk here, but given that `jq` has much the same capabilities and a built-in JSON parser, it seems better to do this natively in `jq`.